# Angular2 components.map is not a function

Tags: node.js, npm, angular

When trying to load an angular webpage, the following error is thrown

```
[1] /Users/dylan/IdeaProjects/angular2-ui-prototype/code/node_modules/angular2-universal/dist/node/bootloader.js:246
[1]         var directives = components.map(function (component) {
[1]                                     ^
[1]
[1] TypeError: components.map is not a function
```

I'm not sure why this error is occuring.

node version: 4.1.2

I can do an `npm run build` without any issues, and `npm run watch`only throws the error once I actually load the page.

This problem started happening after I ran `npm install` after I had cleared both `dist`and `node_modules.

(The complete command used was: `rm -rf dist/ node_modules/ && npm i && npm run build && npm run watch && npm run watch`)

I made the assumption that it was *maybe* due to the version of node, so I did try this with version 4.4.1 as well, and had the same result.

When I scroll up, I do get a bunch of warnings like these:

`npm WARN install:ansi@0.3.1 ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/Users/dylan/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.1/lib/node_modules/.staging/ansi-67bd84a7' -> '/Users/dylan/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.1/lib/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/ansi'`

I get a *lot* of these warnings so I doubt renaming them is the propper way. I could also throw everything away in that folder, and start over, but I'm not sure if at this point I'll do more bad than good :-)

Anything pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the issue, or well, the solution.

I have updated the angular2-universal dependency to `0.101.3` and now everything works as expected.